# Significato di "gestire" in questa frase

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> «Era biondo, alto, franco nel **gestire**.»

Ho cercato il verbo "gestire" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che può significare amministrare o regolare qualcosa oppure fare gesti. Tuttavia non riesco a capire il senso di tale verbo nella frase sopra citata. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: potrebbe essere inteso nel senso di "gestire le situazioni" o "gestire le persone";  per "franco" si intende schietto e disinvolto.
Una seconda ipotesi è che qui "gestire" sia inteso nel senso di "gesticolare" ovvero fare gesti con le mani per accompagnare il discorso. In questo caso significa che il personaggio parlava accompagnandosi con gesti che sottolineavano la sua franchezza ossia la sua onestà (immagino una gesticolazione precisa e aperta).

Comment: Qui *gestire* è adoperato nel senso etimologico di *fare gesti*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato è quello di http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gestire1/

> **gestire**<sup>1</sup> v. intr. [dal lat. *gestire*, der. di *gestus -us* «gesto»] (*io gestisco*, *tu gestisci*, ecc.; aus. *avere*), raro. – Fare gesti con le mani, con le braccia, soprattutto per accompagnare il discorso e dare evidenza ai concetti: *attore che gestisce troppo*.

Si usa molto di più *gesticolare*, che però può avere un senso di “esagerare nei gesti”.

Per *franco* direi che vale il significato 4 in http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/franco2/, quindi *sicuro di sé*, *schietto*.